# What's the difference between a two-blade prop and three-blade?

Tags: aerodynamics, propeller, aircraft-performance

I read that a three blade can improve climb performance and decrease noise.  How does that work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At the absolute simplest, compared to a two-bladed propeller, a slightly smaller three-bladed propeller can produce more thrust at a given RPM, improving climb performance. Because of the smaller diameter, the propeller tips actually travel slower than the equivalent two-bladed design, reducing noise inside and outside the airplane.

Hartzell Propeller has a great [set of technical answers about propellers](http://hartzellprop.com/faq/technical-questions/). Their explanation of why more blades produces less noise is pretty good:

> A 2-blade propeller produces two pressure pulses per revolution, where a 3-blade propeller will produce three smaller pulses per revolution (for the same amount of total thrust) which is inherently smoother and therefore quieter. The 3-blade propeller will generally have a smaller diameter than the 2-blade propeller that it replaces, which also reduces the tip speed and noise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  if it produces more thrust at a given rpm, does the engine use more gas, or the same?

Comment: I imagine it would use more fuel as it's doing more work (producing more thrust). The Hartzell FAQ I linked mentions that two-bladed designs are the most efficient, but that more blades can produce more thrust and therefore can be advantageous.

Comment: A practical aspect using more blades is larger ground clearance.

Comment: @Garrison Neely: a simplification, but for a given engine fuel usage is more or less proportional to power output, as example HP or KW. At a given speed, power output is proportional to thrust.